# Generic type unification: multiple parameters (T,T) vs. multiple parameter lists (T)(T)?

Tags: generics, scala

I'm a bit confused by the difference in type-checking between curried and uncurried generic functions:

```
scala> def x[T](a: T, b: T) = (a == b)
x: [T](a: T, b: T)Boolean
scala> def y[T](a: T)(b: T) = (a == b)
y: [T](a: T)(b: T)Boolean
```

My intuition was that both `x(1, "one")` and `y(1)("one")` should give type errors, but I was wrong:

```
scala> x(1, "one")
res71: Boolean = false
scala> y(1)("one")
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : java.lang.String("one")
 required: Int
              y(1)("one")
                   ^
```

At first I thought there was some sort of implicit casting going on, but that didn't seem to be the case:

```
scala> x(1 :Int, "one" :String)
res73: Boolean = false
```

So what's going on?  What should my intuition be?

Comment: I have seen a duplicate of this a long time ago. I also believe this [almost] exact case is documented in the SLS.

Comment: There we go. I have updated the title with the important term "multiple parameter lists", which is discussed in the SLS :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that in the first case it is upcasting (downcasting?) both arguments such that T:Any.  In the second, it is currying for Int, and then failing on the String.

This seems to bear me out:

```
scala> y(1)_
res1: Int => Boolean = <function1>
```

Comment: Ok, that seems likely, given that `y(1 :Any)("hello")` returns `false`.

Comment: As an interesting side-note, this question seems to call in the assertion made here: http://www.scala-lang.org/node/262 that "then f(x)(y) and g(x, y) are compiled into exactly the same code."

Comment: They are compiled into exactly the same code as methods, but the compiler will let you automatically/easily do different things to them (e.g. conversion to a function is uncurried in `g(x,y)` form and curried in `f(x)(y)` form), even though the bytecode for the underlying method is identical.

Answer (score 10):

Scala tries to determine types one parameter block at a time.  You can see this if you add another parameter and partially apply:

```
def x[T](a: T, b: T)(c: T) = (a == b)
scala> x(1, "one") _
res0: Any => Boolean = <function1>
```

Of course, both `Int` and `String` are `Any` (and `==` is defined on `Any`).

Type parameters which are not used in an earlier block remain free to be used in a later block:

```
def y[T,U](a: T)(b: U)(c: (T,U)) = (a == b)
scala> y(1)("one")
res1: (Int, java.lang.String) => Boolean = <function1>
```

You can also use earlier blocks as default values in later blocks!

```
def z[T,U](a: T)(b: U)(c: (T,U) = (a,b)) = (c._1 == c._2)
scala> z(1)("one")()
res2: Boolean = false
```

Thus, distributing your parameters amongst multiple parameter blocks has consequences both for type inference and for defaulting (and for partial application).